# Facebook code not posting on wall

Tags: facebook, post

I am trying to connect facebook with my android application, I have created application on facebook and got its app ID. Using this ID this code should post on wall of user.
Why the hell following code just toasting "Posted on facebook"  and not posting on my wall?

```
mFacebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Facebook Activity", "After on create");
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize(FacebookActivity.this, PERMISSIONS,
                        new DialogListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        facebook.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                            }
                        });
            }


            Log.d("Facebook Activity", "Logged in in Facebook");
            facebookPost("Testing 1");
            try {
                facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void facebookPost(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // code for facebook post here
            Log.d("Facebook Activity", "Facebook Post Method");
            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(
                    facebook);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("message", string);

                params.putString("name", "Test Name");
                params.putString("caption","Test caption");
                params.putString("link","www.test.com");
                params.putString("description","test description");
                params.putString("picture", "www.somelink.com/image.gif");
            Log.d("Facebook Activity", "Firing Request to facebook");
            mAsyncFbRunner.request("Me/feed", params, "POST",
                    new RequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMalformedURLException(
                                MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Malformed URL Exception",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onIOException(IOException e,
                                Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Internet is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileNotFoundException(
                                FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e,
                                Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Facebook Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Posted to Facebook",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Posted to facebook",
                            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Object());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', 
array(
'message' => 'message . ',
'name' => 'name.',   
'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/biju.nemom',
'description' =>'this is a description',
'picture' => ' images/mis.jpg' 
)
);
```